# Changing the signature of one method

Tags: java

So I have the following method

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void bubbleSort( T[] a)
//public static void bubbleSort(Comparable[] a)
{
    for(int top = a.length-1; top > 0; top--)
        for(int i = 0; i < top; i++)
            if(a[i+1].compareTo(a[i]) < 0)
            {   T tmp = a[i];

                //Comparabl tmp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = tmp;
            }
}
```

How do I change the method signature in order to be able to call it from something like

```
public int sortByTitle()
{
    return Sorting.bubbleSort(lib); // (lib is  lib = new ArrayList<Object>();
}
```

I must not use collection methods or comparator object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making use of the `.compareTo` method which is not implemented by the `Object` class which in turn would not make your Bubble Sort work since there will be no implementation of the `.compareTo` method.

In your case, I think it would be best to create an array list of items which actually implement the comparable interface, which is the opposite of what you are trying to do (change the method signature to fit the method call).

Once that you will have done that, you should be able to call the method by converting the list to an array using [toArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28%29) method.

Another thing worth noting is that your `bubbleSort` method does not return anything, thus your method call should not compile.

Comment: I am getting the following compilation message error:             method bubbleSort in class Sorting cannot be applied to given types;
required: T[]
found: java.util.List<Object>
reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that the argument type java.util.List<Object> conforms to formal parameter type T[]

the operator that you use here cannot be used for the type of value that you are using it for. You are either using the wrong type here, or the wrong operator.

Comment: @valentin: As stated in my answer, you can't pass an entire array of objects for the simple reason that the `Object` class does not implement the `Comparable` interface, which is something you need for your bubble sort mechanism to work. As I suggested in the answer, you will need to use a different datatype which implements the `Comparable` interface. Once you do that, you should be able to get it working. (Please observe other suggestions I made)

Comment: But if I use an array list like you suggest, wouldn't that mean that I have to use list methods to get things like top and bottom to run through it ? I am looking for something that must not use collections methods or comparator object ... am a bit confused :(

Comment: @valentin: In the answer I then suggested how you can switch the list back to an array. Also, if you can't use the comparator then you should not be using the `.compareTo` method.

Comment: thank you @ninti ...I have copied the list into an array ...worked with it and then back to a list

Comment: @valentin: Glad it helped. I am assuming you also created a list of something which implements the `Comparable` interface?

Comment: No need for comparable interface anymore ... I am passing a list of objects as parameter of the function which gets transferred toArray.My objects are made up of strings and .compareTo works. Then at the end of the sorting algorithm I take the array and place it back into the input parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you won't be able to do this until you ensure that the elements of `lib` implement `Comparable` (if you can't compare the elements, you can't sort).

> How do I change the method signature in order to be able to call it from something like

You could change it like so:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void bubbleSort(List<T> a)
```

However, changing the signature won't be enough, since you'd have to use `.size()` instead of `.length`, `.get(i)` instead of `[i]` etc. In other words, you'd have to rewrite the method.

Once again, the method will only be applicable to lists of `Comparable`, not arbitrary lists of `Object`s.